# Symfony CollectionType add data when building without entity

Tags: php, symfony

I'm actually rendering a form, but this one is dynamic, by dynamic i want to say that i generate the Form with an XSD and i dont save an entity but i save the data inside this for, also I generate a template using smarty and the data store in the form, and store the HTML generated for this template in my database.

This form is used to create a Newsletter, everything is fine for the creation, but now i have to save this one as a draft newsletter (i.e. the newsletter is editable and can be editate when the user want...).

So I build my form life for the creation but i passed the data to the type like this :

```
$builder->add($insideElement[0].'-'.$key, NumberType::class, array('required' => false,'data' => $dataAsArray[$key][$insideElement[0]] , 'attr' => array('class'=> $key.'-'.$insideElement[0]) , 'data' => 0,0));
```

But when i'm using the `CollectionType`:

```
$builder->add($key, CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type' => DynamicFormType::class,
    'entry_options' => array('data' => $arrayOfFieldType),
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'prototype' => true,
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'my-selector',
    ),));
```

I passed a `DynamicFormType::class`, here is the code :

```
namespace CoreBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CountryType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;

class DynamicFormType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if(isset($options['data'][0])){
            foreach($options['data'][0] as $key => $field) {
                $label = substr($key,0,strpos($key, "-"));
                if($field[0] == 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType') {
                    $builder->add($key, $field[0], array('data_class' => null, 'required' => false, 'label' => $label, 'attr' => array('style' => 'width: 75%;')));
                }
                elseif($field[0] == 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType') {
                    $builder->add($key, $field[0], array('data' => 0.0, 'label' => $label));
                }
                else {
                    $builder->add($key, $field[0], array('data' => '', 'label' => $label));
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach($options['data'] as $key => $field) {
                $label = substr($key,0,strpos($key, "-"));
                if($field[0] == 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType') {
                    $builder->add($key, $field[0], array('data_class' => null, 'required' => false, 'label' => $label, 'attr' => array('style' => 'width: 75%;')));
                }
                elseif($field[0] == 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType') {
                    $builder->add($key, $field[0], array('data' => 0.0, 'label' => $label));
                }
                else {
                    $builder->add($key, $field[0], array('data' => '', 'label' => $label));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'corebundle_dynamic';
    }
}
```

If someone have an idea to add data to the `CollectionType` when I'm building this one... Or, at another moments...
Feel free to ask me for more code.
Thanks !